# Can different wyvern species breed together?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Ok so I have a level 234 male poison wyvern and a level 229 female lightning wyvern. I had raised them and I believe they are max level. Will I be able to breed the two and get a fertilized egg, or will I need to raise two more wyverns of the opposite gender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot breed [Wyverns](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Wyvern) at all, regardless of their type (barring mods).

The wiki article on [Wyvern Eggs](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Wyvern_Egg_(Scorched_Earth)) states (emphasis mine)

> Wyvern Eggs are **only** found in The World Scar near the blue and red obelisks

Although it states having a Wyvern makes it easier to get more eggs, this relates to their actual movement speed making it easier to steal eggs.

[Messages boards](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/201358-ark-survival-evolved/75094798) confirm that you can't breed your own Wyverns.

In fact, at least one mod exists to [add Wyvern Breeding](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=814833973).

Comment: Hey thanks. Could've sworn they could be bred though. Well at any rate thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can i breed ice wyerns on valguero

Comment: The question is if it's possible to breed wyverns using different species.